# Update the value of a field in database by 1 using codeigniter

Tags: database, activerecord, codeigniter, insert-update

I want to implement a SQL statement using codeigniter active record.

```
UPDATE tags SET usage = usage+1 WHERE tag="java";
```

How can I implement this using Codeigniter active records?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data):

> `set()` will also accept an optional third parameter (`$escape`), that will prevent data from being escaped if set to `FALSE`.

So this should work to pass the increment statement directly to the database:

```php
$this->db->set('usage', 'usage+1', FALSE);
$this->db->where('tag', 'java');
$this->db->update('tags');
```

Because it's not escaped, if you're using a variable instead of a fixed number it should be verified as numeric beforehand.

Comment: Small note on that just to clarify that if you set the optioanl parameter to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.

Comment: what if some one want the value that update field after executing update without using an additional query

Comment: Not possible Ravinder.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use something like this

```
$data = array('usage' => 'usage+1', *other columns*);
$this->db->where('tag', 'java');
$this->db->update('tags', $data);
```

UPDATE: $data was not being passed on to update

Comment: don't forget to send your `$data`. `$this->db->update('tags', $data)`

Comment: @Srihari Goud why it doesn't working 


'$this->db->set('cu_employee_sisa_cuti',"cu_employee_sisa_cuti+cu_employee_jatah_cuti");
    '

Comment: Where did you get the method `$this->db->set` from? there is nothing like that.. we have to prepare an array and use in `$this->db->update('tags', $data);`

Answer (score 2):

I find its sometimes simpler to just write the SQL rather than having Active Record build it for me.

```
$sql = 'update tags set usage=usage+1 where tag=?';
$this->db->query($sql, array($tag));
```